# Why does adding two Counters with timedelta values raise a TypeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime, python-collections

I am trying to add two Counters, which contain timedeltas. Adding the Counters raises the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/collections/__init__.py", line 734, in __add__
    if newcount > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

This raises the exception:

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import timedelta
a = Counter(time=timedelta(microseconds=167242))
a + a
```

However this does not:

```
b = timedelta(microseconds=167242)
b + b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are getting in the way:

1. `Counter` is designed to do discrete counting, that is, the values are integers.
2. `timedeltas` don't define what it means to be compared to zero, though they could have.

Looks like you will need to do your own Counter-like structure.

Comment: Just tried this:
```
>>> b = timedelta(microseconds=167242)
>>> b > 0
```
And got the exception, you're absolutely right! Thanks.